# Can jQuery provide the tag name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got several elements on a HTML page which have the same class - but they're different element types.  I want to find out the tag name of the element as I loop over them - but .attr doesn't take "tag" or "tagname".

Here's what I mean.  Consider these elements on a page:

```
<h1 class="rnd">First</h1>
<h2 id="foo" class="rnd">Second</h2>
<h3 class="rnd">Third</h3>
<h4 id="bar" class="rnd">Fourth</h4>
```

Now I want to run something like this to ensure that my elements all have an id if one wasn't already defined:

```
$(function() {
  $(".rnd").each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (id === undefined || id.length === 0) {
      // this is the line that's giving me problems.
      // .attr("tag") returns undefined
      $(this).attr("id", "rnd" + $(this).attr("tag") + "_" + i.toString());
    }
  });
});
```

The result I would like would be that the H2 and H4 elements would then have an id of

```
rndh2_1
rndh4_3
```

respectively.

Any ideas on how I can discover the tag name of the element represented by "this"?

Comment: Maybe answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8355251/271103

Answer (score 110, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("id", "rnd" + $(this).attr("tag") + "_" + i.toString());
```

should be

```
$(this).attr("id", "rnd" + this.nodeName.toLowerCase() + "_" + i.toString());
```

Comment: You'll need to use this.nodeName.toLowerCase(), as most DOM representations of HTML documents automatically uppercase the nodeName.

Comment: both this.nodeName and this.tagName seem to work for me.  Thanks all!

Comment: +1 for mentioning nodeName. Sometimes, jQuery is one step too far :-)

Comment: +1 jQuery is() doesn't do the job because in the case of h1, h2, etc there are 6 different cases you have to handle if using is().

Answer (score 167):

You could try this:

```
if($(this).is('h1')){
  doStuff();
}
```

See the [docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/is#expr) for more on is().

Comment: To whom it may concern: if you downvote my answer, please tell me why so I can improve it and learn for future SO-answers. Thanks.

Comment: I hate it too. Anyway I upvoted because `nodeName` returns a string that, depending browser, is upper cased or not.

Comment: Assume the following: You don't just have a small selection of possible tags, but it could be any of 100+ html tags. Then you'd need to write: $(this).is('sometag') a 100+ times. I assume this is why some people downvoted your answer.

Comment: Wow...never seen `is('*')` in years. It probably won't answer the OP but it worked for me, thanks, @middus!

Answer (score 53):

Since I've hit this question once before and it didn't help me in my case (I didn't have a `this`, but instead had a jQuery selector instance). Calling [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) will get you the HTML element, by which you can get the [`nodeName`](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t20) as mentioned above.

```
this.nodeName; // In a event handler, 'this' is usually the element the event is called on
```

or

```
$('.hello:first-child').get(0).nodeName; // Use 'get' or simply access the jQuery Object like an array
$('.hello:first-child')[0].nodeName;     // will get you the original DOM element object
```

Comment: first helpful one on the page

Answer (score 46):

You could also use
`$(this).prop('tagName');` if you're using jQuery 1.6 or higher.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. In my design, I had the jquery element handy, but not the original HTML DOM element. This works for me.

Comment: I think this is the exact answer that answers the subject of this question.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You could use the below code:

```
this.tagName
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use the `nodeName` in jQuery since nodeName is a DOM property and jQuery itself do not have a either a `nodeName` function or property. But based on the respondent who first mentioned about this `nodeName` stuff, this is how I was able to resolve the problem:

```
this.attr("id", "rnd" + this.attr("nodeName") + "_" + i.toString());
```

NOTE: `this` here is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a question you come along on google using *jquery tagname first child* as a query I'll post another example:

```
<div><p>Some text, whatever</p></div>

$('div').children(':first-child').get(0).tagName); // ...and not $('div:first-child')[...]
```

The jquery result is an (uppercase) tagname: **P**

Answer (score 0):

Consider the fast **FILTER** method:

```
$('.rnd').filter('h2,h4')
```

returns:

```
[<h2 id=​"foo" class=​"rnd">​Second​</h2>​, <h4 id=​"bar" class=​"rnd">​Fourth​</h4>​]
```

so:

```
$('.rnd').filter('h2,h4').each(function() { /*...$(this)...*/ });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get html element tag name on whole page.

You could use:

```
        $('body').contents().on("click",function () {
          var string = this.tagName;
          alert(string);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can try:
jQuery(this).get(0).tagName;
or
jQuery(this).get(0).nodeName;
```

note:
replace this with your selector (h1, h3 or ...)

Answer (score 0):

I only just wrote it for another issue and thought it may help either of you as well.

**Usage:**

- i.e. `onclick="_DOM_Trackr(this);"`

**Parameters:**

1. DOM-Object to trace
2. return/alert switch (optional, default=alert)

**Source-Code:**

```
function _DOM_Trackr(_elem,retn=false)
{
    var pathTrackr='';
    var $self=$(_elem).get(0);
    while($self && $self.tagName)
    {
        var $id=($($self).attr("id"))?('#'+$($self).attr("id")):'';
        var $nName=$self.tagName;
        pathTrackr=($nName.toLowerCase())+$id+((pathTrackr=='')?'':' > '+(pathTrackr));
        $self=$($self).parent().get(0);
    }
    if (retn)
    {
        return pathTrackr;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(pathTrackr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Example Output: `html > body > div#coreApp > div#productpage > div#productpage-wrapper > div > div > div > div > div#pthumb12 > form#thumb_uploader_src > input`

Comment: **Another usage example:** `$('*').each(function(_i,_e){$(_e).attr('title',_DOM_Trackr(_e,true));});`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to fix your problem, is to replace `$(this).attr("tag")` with either `this.nodeName.toLowerCase()` or `this.tagName.toLowerCase()`.

Both produce the exact same result!

Answer (score 0):

Instead simply do:

```
$(function() {
  $(".rnd").each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (id === undefined || id.length === 0) {
      // this is the line that's giving me problems.
      // .attr("tag") returns undefined
      // change the below line...
      $(this).attr("id", "rnd" + this.tagName.toLowerCase() + "_" + i.toString()); 
  });
});
```