# Get child tagname of an element

Tags: jquery

I want to get the child tag name of an element.

HTML:

```
<div class="element">
    <h1>title</h1>
</div>
<div class="element">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ma66w8WJsZ0/UBVcmt3XS4I/AAAAAAAAAWw/4UyVd2eR8A0/s1600/olympic-logo.thumbnail.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="debugger"></div>
```

​
jQuery:

```
$(".element").bind("click", function(){

    var child = $(this).add("first-child").prop("tagName");

    $("#debugger").html(child);

});​
```

I don't understand why I'm always getting DIV as the result...

Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/8Xg3G/2/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can jQuery provide the tag name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$(this).children()[0].tagName
```

***OR***

```
$(this).children().first().prop('tagName');
```

`.add()` used for add new element to jQuery object array, but you're trying to get an existing element's tag name. So, you need some getter method.

---

***With JavaScript***

```
this.firstChild.tagName
```

**OR**

```
this.childNodes[0].tagName
```

---

***Full Code***

```
$(".element").bind("click", function(){
    var child = $(this).children().first().prop('tagName');
    $("#debugger").html(child);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xg3G/8/)**

Comment: if you're going to use array notation to get the raw DOM element, isn't `.first()` redundant?

Comment: @jackwanders `1+1=2` is same for everyone. Thanks mate.

Comment: For older jQuery versions, use `.attr('tagName')` instead of `.prop('tagName')`

Answer (score 4):

`.add` will add an element to the current jQuery collection, in this case, `$(this)`. `$(this)` contains the `div`, and when you run `.prop('tagName')`, jQuery returns the tag name of the first element in the collection, so you get "div" as a result.

Try `.children` instead:

```
var child = $(this).children().eq(0).prop("tagName");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var child = $(this).children(":first");
```

This will get the first child of `this`.

Pretty sure `.prop('tagName')` only works in jQuery 1.6+.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `target` property of the `event` object, try the following:

```
$(".element").bind("click", function(event){
    var target = event.target.localName; // or event.target.tagName;
    $("#debugger").html(target);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Xg3G/7/)