# jQuery - Check which this element is?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, this

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can jQuery provide the tag name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532331/can-jquery-provide-the-tag-name)

My code:

```
    $('#tab-menu a,#tab-menu li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I need it so that I can execute different code depending on what was clicked so for example

```
if(element == "li")
//do something
else
//do something else
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('#tab-menu a,#tab-menu li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).is("li"))
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#tab-menu a,#tab-menu li').click(function(e) {
   if($(e.currentTarget).is('li')
     ...do stuff here
});
```

Comment: Why `currentTarget` and not `this`?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
if(this.tagName == "LI")  //note the uppercase
```

Edit: oh yeah, or you can use `is()`. But don't give me credit for that if that's what you use.

Comment: `tagName` is a property of the native DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @JamesAllardice whoops. Been a while. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. +1 for the **most efficient answer**! No need to call jQuery again when you can just access a native property.

Comment: `tagName` usually returns an uppercase string.

Comment: @Travesty3 thought about that, but as I don't know the spec I can't guarantee that `tagName` will always be all upper. I think the toLower is ok, it's obviously gonna be negligible.

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt - It will always be uppercase. "For HTML, the tagName parameter may be provided in any case, but it must be mapped to the canonical uppercase form by the DOM implementation." - http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html